# How does KLM calculate the baggage fees when flying on a multi-airline ticket?

Tags: transit, luggage, short-connections, klm, skiing

I bought round-trip tickets for winter holidays to Sofia, Bulgaria from Moscow, Russia with a 14-hour connection in Amsterdam, Netherlands. I want to buy an extra piece of luggage in order to take my ski equipment.

The problem is that each of the 4 flights (Moscow-Amsterdam, Amsterdam-Sofia , Sofia-Amsterdam, Amsterdam-Moscow) is with different airlines (Aeroflot, Bulgaria Air, Transavia, KLM respectively). However all tickets were bought from KLM. Due to these facts I'm confused how many times I should pay for an additional piece of baggage and should the payment be made to KLM or to any company at the airport?

**Edit 1**

*KLM answer*
[image: KLM answer]

Comment: did you try to talk to KLM? I believe if you by thru KLM, it means, you have only one reservation number, you will pay one time.

Comment: @MarcelP. Yeah, i've contacted with them but unfortunately i can't cleary understand their answer (added KLM answer screenshot). In their message they mentioned that "...airline that operates the first flight will calculate the baggage fee" but i'm worried that this fee can be calulated twice and summed due to the fact that flight is operated by 2 companies with different luggage rules.

Comment: You can contact KLM via WhatsApp? Looks really nice!

Comment: @LassiUosukainen yep. Really appreciate this feature!

Comment: I understood that you pay one time and you should do it with the first leg. I already had this issue using different companies and it was the way that worked.

Comment: @MarcelP. in my experience, on a round trip ticket, one pays for excess baggage twice: once one the way out, and once on the way back.

Comment: Yup, I would say that! But not twice to go...you can go with some baggage and come back with less... So, makes sense.

Comment: @MarcelP.@phoog. Thanks for your answers! Hope that it works in a way that you've described:)

Answer (score 1):

According to OP's Whatsapp conversation:

> Extra baggage that you would like to purchase shall be arranged at the airport as your flights are being operated by different airlines. Our colleagues at the airport will apply the rules of the airline that operates the first flight to calculate the baggage fee.